# Add data in List onclick event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add items from textbox into the list and want to display on main page. Here is my code sample

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-controller="purchaseInvoiceInquiryController as c" ng-init="c.initializeController()">
<input type="text" ng-model="c.name" placeholder="Enter the Book" />
<input type="text" ng-model="c.price" placeholder="Enter a Price" />
<button ng-click="c.addBooks()">Add the Book</button></p>
<td ng-repeat="x in c.books"> {{ x.name + ' - ' + x.price}}</td>
```

and angular controller code is :

```
 this.addBooks = function () {
            c.books = [{
                name: c.name,
                price: c.price
            }];
        };
```

Its only add one item in that list when i try to add another item it will override the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize books to empty array in controller and use push method of array to add new books. You may need to add logic to avoid duplicates.

```
this.books = [];
this.addBooks = function () {
  this.books.push({
    name: c.name,
    price: c.price
  });
};
```

Comment: Following Stack Overflow's standards for answering is **important**. Please read here [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Use [push](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) instead.

```
this.addBooks = function () {
            c.books.push({
                name: c.name,
                price: c.price
            });
        };
```

Comment: Thanks resolving my issue i tried this but got error because i can't declare 'c.books = []'